# What is the best way to migrate an SDE Database

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, linux, oracle-spatial

We have a prod database, with an SDE schema.  We want to install a new SDE instance 9.3.1 and link it to a copy of the prod database.

ArcSDE 9.3.1 on Linux SLES 4

Now, what is the best way to do this.  It isn't an upgrade, so you can't really upgrade the SDE install I think?  If you simply install the SDE on top of a pre-existing SDE schema, there are all sorts of links broken, indexes, data issues, etc.

So, if I am correct, then is the only way to go, is to build an empty database (save from the users table) and then import all of the data via sdeimport (obviously using the date from a sdeexport)?

I am not normally involved with SDE, preferring to leave it with those mystical creatures, the DBA's, but I can't find one here (I believe they Apparate and Disapparate without control) so have no option but to do this myself, and find myself without the 100% self belief it is the right way to go.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

We have no way of accessing the original data live, so have to export the Oracle data from one area to another, before we can access it e.g. we cannot simply access the live data 'live' as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Backup your database first [most important]**

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000000q000000

and there is 9.3.1 version

Migrating Oracle data from one storage type to another

http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Migrating%20Oracle%20data%20from%20one%20storage%20type%20to%20another

Process:

- full oracle export from SDE 9.x
- full oracle import into SDE 9.3.1
- upgrade SDE software from 9.x to 9.3.1
- upgrade to high precision
- then apply the update to the storage types

Comment: This is all 9.3.1 so using arcpy isn't an option.

Comment: Hairy the bottom link is for 9.3 and the topic was updated for 9.3.1 "This topic was updated for 9.3.1." Though this can be done outside of ArcGIS if you have very good Oracle SQL skills and knowledge of the SDE structure.

Comment: My main problem, though, Mapperz, is that it's not a straightforward bit of work, as it involves DB dumps, and everything.  What I am doing at the moment, is exporting the data from live, with an sdeexport, then importing it using sdeimport.  This works fine, but is slightly long winded.  However, my great issue comes with a fresh 11g box, migrating the 9i database, then doing the same with sde 9 to 9.3.1.  Bit of a pain really and I dont have any live access to the live data!  Thanks for your advice.

Comment: I think this is about as good as we could hope for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your ArcCatalog for the export of ArcSDE Database in XML.

[image: ArcCatalog export your workspace XML]

And you can export your data and architecture in XML.
After, you create your ArcSDE database and upload your XML.

Good luck.